How do you retrieve most recent Post from a collection of 'posts' in Firestore using Angular?
I'm new to Firebase and Angular and I'm making a Twitter mock-up for practice. I have it to where a user can make a Post and it saves to a collection of 'posts' in Firebase. Now, I'm trying to get it to where the most recent post displays on the HomePage for a start.
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Post } from 'src/interface';
import { AngularFirestore } from '@angular/fire/firestore';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class PostsService {

  postsCollection = this.afs.collection<Post>('posts');

  constructor(private afs: AngularFirestore) {

  }

  const recentPostQuery: Query<Post> = this.postsCollection.ref.orderBy('timestamp', 'desc').limit(1);
  
}

Obviously this code doesn't work. Am I getting close though? How should I set up the observable in this scenario? Any help is appreciated thank you

First, you need to create a service which returns an Observable:
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFirestore } from '@angular/fire/firestore';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Post } from 'src/app/interfaces/post.interface';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class PostsService {

  constructor(private afs: AngularFirestore) {}

  getRecentPost(): Observable<Post | undefined> {
    return this.afs.collection<Post>('posts', ref => ref.orderBy('timestamp', 'desc').limit(1))
      .snapshotChanges()
      .pipe(
        map(actions => {
          const data = actions.map(a => {
            const id = a.payload.doc.id;
            const data = a.payload.doc.data() as Post;
            return { id, ...data };
          });
          return data.length > 0 ? data[0] : undefined;
        })
      );
  }
}

Secondly, create a component which consumes the service like below:
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { PostsService } from 'src/app/services/posts.service';
import { Post } from 'src/app/interfaces/post.interface';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css']
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
  recentPost: Post | undefined;

  constructor(private postsService: PostsService) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.postsService.getRecentPost().subscribe(post => {
      this.recentPost = post;
    });
  }
}

Thirdly, Below Are the components HTML to be followed by receiving data from Firestore to display the values retrieved:
<div *ngIf="recentPost">
  <h2>{{ recentPost.title }}</h2>
  <p>{{ recentPost.content }}</p>
  <p><small>{{ recentPost.timestamp | date }}</small></p>
</div>

Note : use angular-cli to create components or services or manually create components/services by yourself.

Hi,
First, for this line, "const data = actions.map(a => {" I had to adjust it to get rid of a typing error to this, "const data: any = actions.map(a => {"
Second, when I attempt to retrieve the data in HTML, such as {{ recentPost.content }} or {{ recentPost.user }}, it is returned as undefined.
I'm going to figure out why it's returning as undefined but thank you for helping me understand and getting close to a solution!

Appreciate giving an upvote or mark as an answer if it serves the purpose
